# How to align two views in different RelativeLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout

There are two RelativeLayouts, one below the other. Each has two TextViews, which are in the `centerVertical` position.

My problem is: the RelativeLayout above has a TextView whose position is `centerInParent`, and the TextView below has to `alignLeft` to it. However, they are in two different RelativeLayouts.

How do I align them?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's not clear from your image what 2 views you are trying to align. But you can't align views from different viewgroups relative to each other, you'll need to modify your layout so the views have a common parent, or do it programmatically.

Comment: The image that you have shared is pretty unclear. Is the image something you want to achieve? Is it the state you currently have? Which of these TextViews do you want to align? Also, please share your xml so far.

Comment: what alignment or positioning did you really want from the two relativelayout. Your question is not clear

Comment: Are you saying that the TextView on the bottom relative layout has to be start from the rightmost part of the TextView on the top relative layout?

Comment: provide layout file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following two advices, each will work:
1. Don't use two RelativeLayouts, use one instead.
2. If you insist on using two RelativeLayouts, trick is creating a TextView same as the TextView of the above one, put it in the RelativeLayout bellow but make it invisible, and set alignLeft to this invisible TextView.

**Updated**:
Following the comments, this is one of the expected answer: https://gist.github.com/dieforfree/049754f4260e002aa6cc

Comment: Thanks for the advices. the actual situation is a little more complicated, as shown in the pic, there is a red button in the 3rd line, it has to be aligned centerVertical with the left two TextViews(the content are 验证码 and 1111). At first I use one RelativeLayout just as you suggested. However I can't find a proper way to align the three views in the 3rd line(they have to be aligned centerVertical ), would you give a suggestion?

Comment: @desertboat have you considered using a TableLayout? [Table | Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html)

Comment: TableLayout, that's a good idea. However I don't use TableLayout offen, I will it.      Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this what you expect? https://gist.github.com/dieforfree/049754f4260e002aa6cc

Comment: I am in China, the Internet connection is restricted, I can not open it, would you please send it to my email: desertboat@163.com. Thank you very much!

Comment: I got the email. It perfectly solve my problem, it's much simpler TableLayout . Thank you very much. I wish we can keep in touch in the future. Can I keep you email address?

Comment: As you wish.   and you should mark this as the accepted answer to tell the others who encounter the same problem :).